# I have two components and I want to change property into the second component by function in first component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to use method from other component to take data and also I need to use function on the same button to clear his content. Maybe someone has other idea to do same thing.

with the handleAddAsk function I get the data I need, this function is triggered by the ask__btn class button but I also want to use the handleClick function on this button to clear the input after sending the data

```js
//I deleted redundant code

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Ask from './Ask';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    asks: [],
  }

  handleAddAsk(index, name, data) {
    let asks = data[index].asks.push({
      id: data[index].asks.length,
      name: name,
    })
    this.setState({ asks });
  }

}

//second class

class Ask extends Component {
    state = {
        input: '',
    }

    handleChange = e => {
        const name = e.target.name
        const value = e.target.value
        this.setState({
            [name]: value,
        })
    }
    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({
            input: '',
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ask">
                <label className="ask__label">{this.props.name}
                    <input className="ask__input" name="input" value={this.state.input} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="treść pytania ..." />
                </label>
                <button className="ask__btn" onClick={this.props.handleAddAsk.bind(this, this.props.index, this.state.input, this.props.data)}>Dodaj pytanie</button>
            </div >
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a custom event handler function in the Ask class to call the `handleClick` and `this.props.handleAddAsk` then bind that handler function to onClick event. Or Call `this.props.handleAddAsk` function inside `handleClick` and assign the `handleClick` to the onClick event.